# Can't get PIVOT to work

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to use PIVOT for the first time and I am not able to get it to work, I just can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I started with a nasty select statement.  When I get these results I can get results and what I have been doing is exporting to Excel and using the pivot functions in there.  When I get the data into Excel, I do this as my operations:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgxJF.jpg

So I then went to the next step and tried to do the whole pivot in SQL but can't get it to work.  Here is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT #tmp1.AuthID
, #tmp1.ProviderID
, #tmp1.ProviderName
, #tmp1.LOCID
, #tmp1.LOCDesc
, '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(#tmp1.TotAuthAmt AS MONEY),-1) AS 'ToAuthAmt'
, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), #tmp1.AuthDate, 101) AS AuthDate, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), #tmp1.AuthExpirationDate, 101) AS AuthExpirationDate
, DATEDIFF(D,#tmp1.AuthDate,#tmp1.AuthExpirationDate) AS AuthLenInDays
,   (CASE WHEN 
        ISNULL(#tmp2.TotPaidAmt, 0) = 0 THEN '$0.00' 
        ELSE '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(#tmp2.TotPaidAmt AS MONEY),-1) 
    END) AS TotPaidAmt,
#tmp1.NbrOfAuthorizations
, #tmp1.UnitsAuthorized
, #tmp1.RatePerUnit
, #tmp1.CAREMODE
,   (CASE WHEN 
        ISNULL(#tmp2.UnitsAdjudicated, 0) = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE #tmp2.UnitsAdjudicated 
    END) AS AuthUnitsClaimed
, (#tmp1.UnitsAuthorized - 
    (CASE WHEN 
        ISNULL(#tmp2.UnitsAdjudicated, 0) = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE #tmp2.UnitsAdjudicated 
    END)) AS UnclaimedAuths
,   (CASE WHEN 
        ISNULL(#tmp2.ExpiredAuths, 0) = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE 1 
    END) AS ExpiredIndicator

FROM (SELECT 
DISTINCT #tmp1.AuthID
, #tmp1.ProviderID
, #tmp1.ProviderName
, #tmp1.LOCID
, #tmp1.LOCDesc
, '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(#tmp1.TotAuthAmt AS MONEY),-1) AS 'ToAuthAmt'
, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), #tmp1.AuthDate, 101) AS AuthDate
, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), #tmp1.AuthExpirationDate, 101) AS AuthExpirationDate
, DATEDIFF(D,#tmp1.AuthDate,#tmp1.AuthExpirationDate) AS AuthLenInDays
, (CASE WHEN 
        ISNULL(#tmp2.TotPaidAmt, 0) = 0 THEN '$0.00' 
        ELSE '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CAST(#tmp2.TotPaidAmt AS MONEY),-1) 
    END) AS TotPaidAmt,
#tmp1.UnitsAuthorized
, #tmp1.RatePerUnit
, #tmp1.CAREMODE
,   (CASE WHEN 
        ISNULL(#tmp2.UnitsAdjudicated, 0) = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE #tmp2.UnitsAdjudicated 
    END) AS AuthUnitsClaimed
, (#tmp1.UnitsAuthorized - 
    (CASE WHEN 
        ISNULL(#tmp2.UnitsAdjudicated, 0) = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE #tmp2.UnitsAdjudicated 
    END)) AS UnclaimedAuths
,   (CASE WHEN 
        ISNULL(#tmp2.ExpiredAuths, 0) = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE 1 
    END) AS ExpiredIndicator
FROM #tmp1
LEFT JOIN #tmp2 
ON #tmp2.AuthID = #tmp1.AuthID 

GROUP BY #tmp1.AuthID, #tmp1.ProviderID, #tmp1.LOCID, #tmp1.LOCDesc, #tmp1.UnitsAuthorized, #tmp1.RatePerUnit, #tmp1.FamilyID, #tmp1.ProviderName, #tmp1.TotAuthAmt,
#tmp1.AuthDate, #tmp1.AuthExpirationDate, #tmp2.TotPaidAmt, #tmp1.NbrOfAuthorizations, #tmp1.CAREMODE, #tmp2.UnitsAdjudicated, #tmp2.ExpiredAuths
)#tmp1

PIVOT (
SUM(#tmp1.NbrOfAuthorizations) FOR ProviderName
IN (#tmp1.ProviderName)
) AS #tmp1
```

What do I need to change here to get this to work?  Also, how would I add the other items as shown in the screen shot?

EDIT1:  Looks like I was able to get results after using this for my PIVOT:

```
PIVOT
(SUM(NbrOfAuthorizations) FOR [ProviderName] IN (element1, element2, etc.)

) PivotResults1

PIVOT
(AVG(AuthLenInDays) FOR [CAREMODE] IN ([element1])

) PivotResults2
```

but still having a couple of issues...the SUM statement doesn't actually seem to SUM the values for a specific value into one column.  I see a '1' or NULL for each cell, as in this example:  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query .  The other thing is for my AVG column, I can't figure out how to change the name of that column, it is always the name of element1.

Comment: The way to approach this is to keep taking bits out until it works and then add the complexity back in.

Comment: true! start easy, take out complicated columns, reduce the problem to a basic version.

Comment: you can also use aliases for your tables, like `FROM #tmp1 as t1` and then refer columns like `t1.RatePerUnit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think instead of

```
IN (#tmp1.ProviderName)
```

you need

```
IN ([element1],[element2],[element3], ... )
```

with element*n* being all variations of content of #tmp1.ProviderName. In the SELECT part at the very top you must then list these elements as columns

and

you should give different aliases to the two table statements, you have #tmp1 twice in there.

Try an easy test example of PIVOT with much less columns first. If You figure it out it is *very* powerful. I love the pivot features in excel (pivotcharts!) but the database can do aggregation so much faster.